# Pound Signs Disappearing from H3s

Tags: html, css, special-characters, cufon, font-replacement

The pound signs (£) `&pound;` work perfectly within `<p>` tags, but are not showing up at all in the H3s on [the site I'm building](http://sculptcoach.com/personal-trainer-primrose-hill.html).

Edit: It looks like the issue is with the font cufon. But, I can't find this font (or H3) in the css.

Comment: What are all the `cufon` tags about? I suspect that might be the source of your problem, since your `p`-tags do not contain any of this.

Comment: The font you are using for `cufon` perhaps does not have the pound sign? Perhaps cufon is not parsing the `&pound;` HTML entity correctly. Why don't you look into using [Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) as an alternative to cufon?

Comment: @Tara: It may be better if you mention Cufon use in the question by editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload the font file to Cufon you want to tick the Punctuation box as well as letters and numerals. Otherwise it won't render any punctuation you have between Cufon enabled tags.

[image]

Your site is loading Cufon here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/droid_sans_400-droid_sans_700.font.js"></script>
```

What you'll need to do is generate a new Cufon file (http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) with the box ticked in the image and replace the file **js/droid_sans_400-droid_sans_700.font.js** with the new one that includes the punctuation.

Personally I would use as similar a Google Font as possible. Cufon has some issues with IE.

Comment: Thanks, the strange thing is, I can't find 'h3' or 'cufon' in the css doc at all. (It's from a template.) Any idea where it might be coming from?

Comment: Lines 8 and 9. That's where Cufon's being set. Is there any way you can re upload the font to generate a new js file?

Comment: I've edited lines 8 & 9 to this 'font:normal 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background:#fff;', but it's still showing up the same...

Comment: Thank you Space :) I've just cut those lines out so it's a regular font now.

Comment: No worries. Have you thought about adding a Google font instead? It's loads easier to get to grips with - http://www.google.com/webfonts#ChoosePlace:select